# How can I prefetch images with AlamofireImage using the uiprefetching delegate?

Tags: swift, uitableview, alamofire, prefetch

I'm trying to implement the UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching delegate for my tableView using AlamofireImage. But how can I set up this?

I already added the delegate and in my viewDidLoad I've set:

```
self.tableView.prefetchDataSource = self
```

and then the relative methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
         indexPaths.forEach {}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cancelPrefetchingForRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        indexPaths.forEach {}
```

And in my cellForRowAt indexPath method I download images like this:

```
let url = URL(string: car.fotoUrl)!

        cell.imageCar.af_setImage(
            withURL: url,
            placeholderImage: placeholderImage,
            imageTransition: .crossDissolve(0.2),
            runImageTransitionIfCached: false,
            completion: { response in
                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    self.dismissLabel()
                } else if response.error?._code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet{
                    self.showLabel()
                }
```

To sum up I want to preload the images in the prefetch methods to improve the tableview scrolling and not downloading them each time a cell is presented.

Answer (score 1):

UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader.downloadImages(URLRequests: requests)

Put it somewhere before showing collection view cell. Next time images will be tooked from cache.

Comment: I need to set this in the prefetchRowsAt method?

Comment: Value of type 'ImageDownloader' has no member 'downloadImages'

Comment: http://prntscr.com/n5x769

You can preload it where you need. At session start, previous screen. Same with method you described, but need to use download method for single item instead.

Comment: @NoemiPecorari - Yes, in `prefetchRowsAt`, and of course setting the `prefetchDataSource` for your table view. Note it’s just `download(_:)`, not `downloadImages(URLRequests:)`. And in AlamofireImages 4.x, it’s now `UIImageView.af.sharedImageDownloader.download(requests)` (no underscore).